# How to guarantee in layout xml that a certain element is displayed at its full height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I'm new to Android and noticed that when creating a `TabHost` with a `LinearLayout` that includes `FrameLayout` and `TabWidget`, order of declaration is very important. For example, if I use:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" />
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

... the `TabWidet` will never be displayed because the `FrameLayout` takes up the whole space. But if I declare the `TabWidget` first:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

... both are displayed but the `TabWidget` is on the top rather than the bottom which is what I desire.

So, I was wondering if there is a `layout_height` specification or other attribute that can "guarantee" a certain element is rendered at its full height before the others are considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your first example you are telling the frame layout to take as much height as he needs depending on how many content he has:

```
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
```

I assume he leaves no space for the TabWidget.

The answer to your question is:

```
android:layout_(dimension) = "fill_parent"
```

This one takes full space.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I tried `fill_parent` but the problem is that the order is important, so since I want `FrameLayout` to be on top of `TabWidget`, whether I specify `wrap_content` or `fill_parent` it has the effect of filling the entire screen leaving no room for the poor tab bar.

Comment: If you want to draw both widgets I recommend you to use android:weight attribute, this will certainly help you scaling the widgets as you want to, or there is another solution specifying the exact height and width of the widget in pixels, but I don't recommend it to you cause it doesn't scales between different screen sizes.The first solution is better.Good Luck